# Angular table selecting and highlighting all the column and row of a table

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, html-table

I am trying to highlight a row and column of a table. I want to collect the highlighted row and column in an array. Below are the changes I am trying to do

```
<table class="sjs-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of test">
      <td *ngFor="let val of row">
        {{val}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

sheet-component.ts

```
export class SheetJSComponent {
 
  test:[]= [
   
    [
        "Year",
        "Month",
        "Facebook",
        "Reddit",
        "LinkedIn",
        "Instagram"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        1,
        "50",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        2,
        "80",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        3,
        "120",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        4,
        "75",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        5,
        "60",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        6,
        "80",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        7,
        "95",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        8,
        "55",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        9,
        "45",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        10,
        "80",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        11,
        "90",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [
        2019,
        12,
        "110",
        "20",
        "25",
        "20"
    ],
    [],
    [
        "This is system generated excel sheet."
    ]
];

 
 
}
```

I would like to highlight the column and row when the user hover or click on that particular row or column as shared in the below image. As my understanding of css is very limited any help would be very helpful.

expected highlighted column:

[image]

Stackblitz details https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-upload-3jfrkz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsheet.component.html

Comment: You always want the "linkedIn" column to be highlighted? Or is the column supposed to be highlighted after the user hovers or clicks on it?

Comment: After the user hover or click on that particular column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

**Sample running:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-upload-jbwzyy?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/sheet.component.html

**HTML:**

```
<table class="sjs-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of test; let j = index" (click)="getData(j, row)">
      <td
        *ngFor="let val of row; let i = index"
        (click)="getData1(i)"
        [class.highlight]="i === rows"
      >
        {{ val }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr />

Clicked Column: {{ data }}
```

**Edits to TypeScript:**

```
  getData(data, row) {
    console.log(row);
    this.col = data;
  }

  getData1(val) {
    if (this.col === 0) {
      this.rows = val;
      this.data = this.test[0][val];
      this.total = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        this.total.push(this.test[i][val]);
      }
      this.data = this.test[0][val] + '->' + this.total;
    }
  }
```

**Explanation:**

Here I am trying to get the index of both column and row and the row's data in the getData method. And then matches with the current row and column index to highlight. and you play around the way you want.

Comment: I am looking to select all the columns (Vertically) or row(Horizontal).. You are selecting a single cell and corresponding to that you are fetching only the row values(2019,6,80,20,25,20). For example, If I clicked or hover on Reddit. It should highlight all the columns vertically and fetched value like(20,20,20,20,20)

Comment: Updated above on the simulator

Comment: You are still fetching all the rows(2019,6,80,20,25,20) instead of columns(20,20,20,20,20)...

Comment: No, this is the data I am displaying Clicked Column: Facebook->50,80,120,75,60,80,95,55,45,80,90,110. I refresh the link of the simulation

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**html file**:

```
<table class="sjs-table">
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of test">
  <td *ngFor="let val of row; let i = index" [class.highlight]="i === 4">
    {{ val }}
  </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**css file:**

```
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-upload-l9rxbw?file=src/app/sheet.component.css

Comment: I want to highlight on the hover or click on that column...I a also want to collect the selected coulmn or row in an array